# Reused MCU unit does not work

Tags: pcb-design, soldering

I had a board with ATMEGA16 (SMD package) micro controller and I had to program through ICSP and it was working fine. Later I needed to make some changes on the board. So I designed a new board and transferred all the components to the new board. Now I am using the same ICSP programming technique but it does not read micro controller.

Could soldering and desoldering the IC with Hot blower be the problem? I soldered, de-soldered, soldered again.

Comment: Layout error in the new board, or soldering defect are more likely.  If you suspect that you have cooked the microcontroller while de-soldering, then use a fresh one, and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Layout is fine, continuity is also fine. And the problem is i don't have another MCU in spare :D

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you still have a continuity problem, even though you checked it.  Heat it up with your heat gun, and gently tap it with your tweezers, or something similar, after the solder reflows.  If no luck, try redoing it as shown on the instruction site SolderGuy.com